# how to show bot in microsoft teams for all the people in organization

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, channel

I want to show up Chat bot to all the people in the project

Curently if anyone want to see the bot ,the person need to search appid in microsoft teams and then we are able to connect to chatbot

But i want something like bot should be visible in either chat window/apps to all the people in project by default

Can anyone suggest how can we do this else can please share the supported documents

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Could you please take a look at [Publish your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/manage-apps?toc=%2Fmicrosoftteams%2Fplatform%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2FMicrosoftTeams%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json) to your organisation. Your app needs to be added by the admin of the tenant in the teams admin center to be visible to all the members in the organisation.

Comment: @VaraPasad-MSFT -thanks that actually helped but i dont want to show up to entire organisation ,need to show only to my project which is part of organisation.do you have any idea how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

In the Microsoft Teams Admin centre (https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/) there is a section called "Teams apps", which allows you to define different policies. Inside there, you can (a) define a policy and (b) assign it to a set group of users. These policies allow you to:

1. make an app available to a specific group
2. auto-install this app for these people, and even pin it to the left menu in Teams, for these users.

So you could have a policy created (by your admin) just for the respective project team.